# Having problems with Dojo making HTTP requests on a HTTPS site

Tags: https, dojo

I'm attempting to use a vBulletin plugin called "MGC Chatbox Evo". This plugin uses the Dojo library, but I'm having some trouble making it work via HTTPS.

Within the plugin, the library is called as such:

```
$js .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"></script>';
```

This loads that particular fine over HTTPS. However, this subsequently seems to attempt to load further files, of which I can find absolutely no reference of in the source files for the plugin (using find in Notepad++). I wondered if anyone had any idea as to how I can force these requests to be made via HTTPS instead of HTTP, as they are currently being automatically blocked. Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucOTd.png

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to modify that script tag to load Dojo 1.6.2 instead of 1.6.1?  I think that may fix your problem.

Here's why.  This is from the uncompressed CDN version of `dojo.xd.js` in 1.6.1:

```
dojo.registerModulePath("dojo", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo");
dojo.registerModulePath("dijit", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dijit");
dojo.registerModulePath("dojox", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojox");
```

Then here's the same lines from 1.6.2:

```
dojo.registerModulePath("dojo", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dojo");
dojo.registerModulePath("dijit", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dijit");
dojo.registerModulePath("dojox", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dojox");
```

These paths instruct Dojo where to load additional modules that are requested via `dojo.require`.  Notice that the URLs in 1.6.1 are hard-coded to http, but in 1.6.2 are protocol-relative.